# How to get the names from elements Beautiful Soup 4 has parsed

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a simple HTML file I want to convert. Depending on the class of the tag I need to modifiy the content:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Eine einfache HTML-Datei</TITLE>
<meta name="description" content="A simple HTML page for BS4">
<meta name="author" content="Uwe Ziegenhagen">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H1>Hallo Welt</H1>

<p>Ein kurzer Absatz mit ein wenig Text, der relativ nichtssagend ist.</p>

<H1>Nochmal Hallo Welt!</H1>

<p>Schon wieder ein kurzer Absatz mit ein wenig Text, der genauso nichtssagend ist wie der Absatz zuvor.</p>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I go through the BS4 tree and do certain modifications depending on whether I have a "H1" or "p" or another class of tag? I imagine I need some switch statement to decide at each element how to deal with it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ("simple.html", "r") as htmlsource:
  html=htmlsource.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for item in soup.body:
  print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup tag objects have a `name` property which you can check. For example, here's a function which transforms the tree by adding the string "Done with this " + the appropriate tag name to each node in a postwalk:

```
def walk(soup):
    if hasattr(soup, "name"):
        for child in soup.children:
            walk(child)
        soup.append("Done with this " + soup.name)
```

NB. the `NavigableString` objects representing textual content and the `Comment` objects representing comments don't have attributes such as `name` or `children`, so if you walk the entire tree like above, you need to check if you actually have a tag in hand (which I'm doing with the `hasattr` call above; I suppose you could check that the type is `bs4.element.Tag`).

Comment: NB. this is meant to be called on a tag element. If called on a document, it would also modify `<head>` and its children, the `<html>` element and the entire document (the `BeautifulSoup` object).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open ("simple.html", "r") as htmlsource:
    html=htmlsource.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for item in soup.body:
    print(item)

# You will select all of elements in the HTML page
elems = soup.findAll()
for item in elems:
   try:
      # Check if the class element is equal to a specified class
      if 'myClass' == item['class'][0]:
         print(item)

     # Check if the tagname element is equal to a specified tagname
     elif 'p' == item.name:
        print(item)

  except KeyError:
     pass
```

Comment: I guess it won't work. What I need is some code, that allows me to go through the tree and to decide at each element, what to do with is, using some switch statement. Like for example: if next element is h1, print it's content in bold, if it's a paragraph print it in italics, etc...